React Vite: Blank Screen After New Build Deployment on AWS Until Manual Refresh
I am facing an issue with my React application built using Vite. When a new build is deployed, users who have the application open encounter a blank screen when they try to navigate. Refreshing the page once resolves the issue, and the application works as expected after that.
Error in Browser Console:
https://somedomain.com/assets/componentName-C7AX9YJh.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Current Setup:
Frontend Framework: React
Build Tool: Vite
Deployment: AWS
vite.config.js:
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import path from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
  },
  define: {
    global: {},
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {},
    outDir: "build",
  },
});

How can I ensure that users always load the latest version of the app when a new build is deployed?
Is there a way to handle this scenario programmatically to prevent the blank screen and require a manual refresh?
Any help or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
